# Reading/Writing from byte[]

Tags: java, arrays, byte

Is there any way in java to read/write integer, boolean and string from byte[]?

```
Like:
write(50550);
write(true);
write("bla bla");

And then:
int i = readInt();
int j = readBoolean();
String res = readUTF();
```

Walter and fge answered two different ways to achive this. The only question remains: "Which way is faster?"

Comment: `String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)` to convert from `byte[]` to `String`

Comment: @Yoda NO! This will lose information

Comment: @fge He didn't state the purpose. Altough, ok.

Comment: I want to have something like c++: stdext::writeULE16, stdext::writeULE32, stdext::writeULE64 and stdext::readULE16, stdext::readULE32, stdext::readULE64

Comment: What about using plain serialization?

Comment: Wait, is that byte data only? You also write text in it. Recall that Java strings are not "plain" C `char *`.

Comment: You really need UTF-64 encoding?

Comment: @saka1029 those won't be compatible with UTF encoding.

Comment: @PeterLawrey eh? I rather read that as "Unsigned Little Endian" etc; what troubles me is the mixed text in it though (and there is no such thing as UTF-64 anyway)

Comment: @fge I have a client which uses `UTF-9` so whom an I to judge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(0x1000);
    buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);

    buffer.putInt(100);
    //store booleans as 1 or 0 in a byte
    buffer.put((byte) (true ? 1 : 0));
    buffer.put((byte) (false ? 1 : 0));

    //store string as [int length, byte array]
    String str = "Hello World!";
    byte[] strBytes = str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8); //use any charset you want here
    buffer.putInt(strBytes.length);
    buffer.put(strBytes);


    buffer.flip();
    byte[] data = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
    buffer.get(data);
    System.out.println("Total Bytes: " + data.length);


    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);

    System.out.println(bb.getInt());
    System.out.println(bb.get() != 0);
    System.out.println(bb.get() != 0);
    byte[] inStr = new byte[bb.getInt()];
    bb.get(inStr);
    String myStr = new String(inStr, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println(myStr);
```

Comment: Note: the OP asked for Little Endian and UTF-16 etc but I don't know why you got a down vote.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream`.

Both wrap over resp.an `InputStream` and an `OutputStream` and can read/write various primitive types, "transformed UTF" data etc.

As to writing to a byte array in itself, you want to use a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, and wrap that `DataOutputStream` over it:

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
final DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(out);

// use dataOut; then:

final ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
final DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(in);

// read back
```

---

Anyway, in one of your comments it is also unclear what you want to do; if this is binary data only then go for a `ByteBuffer` instead; you can change its endianness at will before you use it (by default it's big endian), wrap byte arrays in it etc... With the difference that Java has no such thing as unsigned primitive integer types (well, save for `char` but this one is a peculiar beast).

All in all, this looks like a XY problem, so I suggest you edit your question and fully explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)
That is what i was looking for!

Comment: Well OK, but please read the full question. It appears to me that you didn't explain everything...

Comment: Walter and fge answered two different ways to achive this. The only question remains: "Which way is faster?"

Comment: Hold on; have you read my comment yet? What do you think your "text" is? Is this actual data? As I already mentioned, this seems to be a XY problem so please fully describe your problem (and note that you can only accept one answer; I don't really care whether it is mine or not, just so that you know)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be searching from DataInputStream and DataOutputStream.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
// Like:
dos.writeInt(50550);
dos.writeBoolean(true);
dos.writeUTF("bla bla");
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();

DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
// And then:
int i = dis.readInt();
boolean flag = dis.readBoolean();
String res = dis.readUTF();

System.out.println("i: " + i + ", flag: " + flag + ", res: '" + res + "'");
```

prints

```
i: 50550, flag: true, res: 'bla bla'
```

> stdext::writeULE16, stdext::writeULE32, stdext::writeULE64 and stdext::readULE16, stdext::readULE32, stdext::readULE64

This implies you need a text format in which case I suggest using PrintWriter

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(baos, "UTF-16LE"));
// Like:
pw.println(50550);
pw.println(true);
pw.println("bla bla");
pw.close();
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();

Scanner in = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes), "UTF-16LE"));
// And then:
int i = in.nextInt();
boolean flag = in.nextBoolean(); in.nextLine(); // discard the rest of the line
String res = in.nextLine();

System.out.println("i: " + i + ", flag: " + flag + ", res: '" + res + "'");
```

prints the same except the underlying bytes will be in UTF-16LE encoding. This approach also supports UTF-16BE, UTF-32LE, UTF-32BE (and UTF-8)